# Laravel Scout v.s. MySQL Full Text Index?

Tags: laravel, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, laravel-scout

I'm pretty new to Laravel and I've already got a light Laravel app running in production.

Now I have to implement a full-text search (e.g. search content in all posts), I came across these options:

1. [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout)
2. [MySQL Full-Text Index](http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search/)
3. 1+2 => [Laravel Scout MySQL Driver](https://github.com/yabhq/laravel-scout-mysql-driver)

Provided our current DAU is only 100+ and probably a few hundred searches a day, but hopefully, it will be scaled 100+ times later soon.

Which one should I go for and any Pro and Con between them? Anyone using Scout MySQL Driver instead of the default Algolia and is that worth the effort?

Answer (score 2):

I've only used Algolia, so I will only talk about my opinion on Algolia. It's super fast and easy to implement, it also has many components for the popular Js frameworks(VUE, REACT) and even with vanilla Js. The components are really appealing to me, like InstantSearch, AutoComplete and many others. The only thing maybe is the money! We are ok with the STARTER plan which is 29/mo, but again this really depends on your budget and search volume.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I would also like to know the development cost using Aloglia using Laravel. (We don't have frontend for now, so everything is API backed)

Comment: @RichardFu, that's the thing if you do not want to build the most beautiful website, a lot of the widgets are ready to use, you can also customize those, but the default ones are fine for me. And the Alogia laravel package is also well maintained, I am not saying other packages are bad, I mean Aloglia one seems more active. Plus Alogia support is good, and a lot of laravel alogia questions already answered. So in my opinion, if you are ok with the money then Alogia is a really good one.